# $_FILES Empty When Uploading

Tags: php, file-upload, undefined

When trying to access the `$_FILES` array, PHP returns the error

> "Undefined index: picture".

In my `php.ini` file, `File Uploads` are turned on, and any user can write in the `/tmp` directory. In the HTML form, enctype is set to `"multipart/form-data"`. Interestingly enough, the basename for the uploaded file prints so I believe that PHP has actually seen the file, but has some problem uploading it.
Can someone provides suggestions on potential solutions to this problem? By the way, I am using PHP5.

Snippets from PHP File

```
echo "Picture=" . $_POST['picture'] . "<br/>";
$uploadedPic = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="PHPFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p> Picture </p>
<input type = "file" id="picture" name="picture"/>

</form>
```

Comment: have you tried var_dumping your $_FILES?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Javascript to serialize your form?

Comment: is post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in your php.ini set to a large enough value?

Comment: I used print_r to print the contents of the $_FILES array, and it printed an empty array. For some awkward reason, it works now. All I had to do was restart the server. I did not change any settings whatsoever, and the file is less than 40KB.

Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: I recently just had this issue and it was because I forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form declaration, I see you didn't but in case anyone else gets here.

Answer (score 6):

On what line do you get that warning? If it is the one with `$_POST['picture']`, then its logical, you wont find uploaded file data in `$_POST`, it is in `$_FILES`

Comment: On a sidenote.... you will want to check if the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' if you are just uploading a file in your form and not submitting any other data

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Picture=" . $_POST['picture'] . "<br/>";
```

The POST variable

```
$_POST['picture']
```

doesn't exist, so yes, it's going to give an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'll say it here.

MAN, this echo will print the file name! It works! He said it works.

> Interestingly enough, the basename for the uploaded file prints so I believe that PHP has actually seen the file[...]

A good hint: try to `var_dump` the `$_FILES` and add here it's contents. You may have an error because the file is too big, or some other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

What level or error reporting are you using?
`error_reporting(E_ALL)` will turn on full reporting and might give you a hint.
As previously described, do a print of `$_FILES` with `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to see information for your file.

Answer (score 0):

lol, a previous poster said that restarting their server fixed it.  i did the same, and for some reason it works. i made no code changes, and  IIS resets didn't work either. it required a reboot of the computer itself.  that's about 2hrs completely lost.

Answer (score -2):

try adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
```

before

```
<input type = "file" id="picture" name="picture"/>
```