# Uploading and parsing a file with PHPExcel and NginX

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx, yii, phpexcel

So, I'm trying to upload xls and xlsx files to my server (NginX on a Yii framework), which has a php script to parse the data and add it to the database.

Simple enough.

However, I'm stumbling at the first block; when uploading the file, PHPExcel can't seem to find the file -and to be honest, I'm not sure it's there, because I can't get a solid understanding of where it *should* be. Below is my code

```
<code>
<?php
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload')); 

/** Include path **/

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/usr/share/nginx/www/dashboard/protected/extensions/phpexcel/Classes/');


/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */

include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));

echo $_FILES . "<br />";

$inputFileName = $_POST;

foreach ($inputFileName as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
    }
    echo $inputFileName["file"] . "<br />";

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName["file"],PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />'; 

//This is where it breaks  
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName["file"]);
</code>
```

And when it breaks, it hands me this error:

```
<code>
Could not open Active, Telemetered, Electricity Accounts 17-10-2012.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.
</code>
```

and this stack trace:

```
<code>
 /**  
225      * Can the current PHPExcel_Reader_IReader read the file?  
226      *  
227      * @param     string         $pFileName  
228      * @return     boolean  
229      * @throws Exception  
230      */
231     public function canRead($pFilename)  
232     {  
233         // Check if file exists  
234         if (!file_exists($pFilename)) {  
235             throw new Exception("Could not open " . $pFilename . " for reading! File does not exist.");  
236         }  
237 
238         // Check if zip class exists  
239         if (!class_exists('ZipArchive',FALSE)) {  
240             throw new Exception("ZipArchive library is not enabled");  
241         }  
</code>
```

Now, as I understand it, pathinfo() should have given PHP what it needs to find the file, and that file should be living in php's temp folder once I hit the upload button (simple html form; I can get the filename from $_POST, so I know it gets that far), but either it's not actually *uploading* or it's getting lost once it's up.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: html upload form:

```
<code>
<form action="testFile" method="post">
<label for="file" />
<input type="file" name="file"   />
<br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
</code>
```

EDIT:

The html upload form was at fault; since I didn't set the enctype, $_FILES didn't get populated. Setting the encoding to multipart/form data let me get at the information I needed. Thank you both!

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the file upload?  In general, you need to access the global [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array to get uploaded file info.

Comment: @ernie: Added my form's code. I looked at $_Files, but when I tried to access it (the same way I do $_POST, through a foreach, above), it doesn't return anything, so imagined it wasn't being populated.

Comment: can you post a print_r of $_FILES?  You should have $_FILES['file']['name'], $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], and a few other keys.

Comment: Hmm. The results of `echo print_r( $_FILES, TRUE );` are 'Array ( )' So apparently I'm not giving $_FILES the document..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346289/files-empty-when-uploading

Comment: Aaaand there I went, stumbling over the first hurdle. It was my upload form: I wrote it from memory and didn't have the enctype set, which is a problem for someone who wants to upload a file. Thank you, @ernie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Yii use the `CUploadedFile` class, call `getInstance` to get access and information regarding the uploaded files. According to [Yii Documentation on CUploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile)

> CUploadedFile represents the information for an uploaded file.
>
> Call getInstance to retrieve the instance of an uploaded file, and then use saveAs to save it on the server. You may also query other information about the file, including name, tempName, type, size and error.

For example:

```
$form->model->xlsx = CUploadedFile::getInstance($form->model, 'xlsx');
//save the file, as an example I am assuming that file is an xlsx
$file = '/importedfiles/'.uniqid().".xlsx";
if($model->xlsx->saveAs($file))
{
//import PHPExcel if you have not already done so
Yii::import('sharedLibraries.PHPExcel.PHPExcel',true);
                
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
..........
}
else
{
//handle the error as file could not be saved
}
```

Comment: That's really cool. This project needs to move forward right now, but the next one I do, I'll try that method out.