# php $_FILES empty

Tags: php, file-upload

I got a file upload form using `enctype=multipart/form-data`, but my `$_FILES` array is always empty. `max_upload_size` is big enough (2MB, I'm testing with 100kb files). the exactly same code is working on other hosts, so I think something is wrong with my webhoster's php settings. does anyone know what I could check for? when I ask them they always tell me it can't be their fault -_-

**EDIT:**

You asked for code, I didn't post it because it's pretty complicated (a Shopware plugin), but I think I can extract the important parts:

HTML (Smarty):

```
<form method="post" action="{url action=saveRegister}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

PHP (inside my event handler):

```
file_put_contents('ul.log',serialize($_FILES));
```

Result (var_dumped unserialized):

```
array(0) {}
```

Full Form HTML: http://pastebin.com/Wq1yBTux

Comment: Is your code `confidential` to post it here ?

Comment: Check the permissions on the folder you are trying to upload to

Comment: Check the phpinfo outputs

Comment: @PatsyIssa the move hasn't been made yet, the file should be in the tmp folder and the $_FILES array would be populated, we aren't at the stage that the file cannot be moved to the upload directory yet

Comment: Check for `suhosin` parameters, they can be very tricky.

Comment: have you tried print_r($_FILES) to see if the array is populated at all?

Comment: @pythonian29033 we are if the upload folder is set up in `php.ini` file.

Comment: Yup, but that is unsafe anyway, the OP seems like a beginner, I doubt he/she'd be updating php.ini if they don't know how to upload a file yet

Comment: @nonchip have you checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346289/files-empty-when-uploading?rq=1 out yet?

Comment: have you got any other fields in the form? if so are you getting those at your PHP script?

Comment: @pythonian29033 actually, I'd not call myself a beginner, I know how the php.ini works and how to upload files, as I said it works on other servers, the problem is my hoster doesn't let me even read the php.ini

Comment: @bansi yes, $_POST works as expected

Comment: @PatsyIssa pythonian29033 is right, I'm dumping $_FILES before even attempting to move. and the permissions in both the temp folder and the folder I'm moving to are correct.

Comment: As you are saying the script works on other servers, have you checked the PHP version? `$_FILES` was introduced in PHP 4.1.0

Comment: @bansi PHP Version 5.3.23-pl0-gentoo

Comment: @Thibault suhosin seems disabled

Comment: Could you post your form's html ? It might be something as simple as the File input not having a name.

Comment: @PatsyIssa http://pastebin.com/Wq1yBTux, but as I said, same code works on other hosts, so it should not be the html.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error: some "security feature" of the framework "cleaned up" $_POST, so `move_uploaded_file` couldn't check if the file was uploaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

Install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) (see network tab) or [Livehttpheaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) to see if your file is actually sent to the server and if the HTTP headers are correctly send by the browser.

They might be wrong for any reason (Content-Type not allowed, POST method not allowed)

It should give you data to look at and configuration parameters to check.

Comment: it's sent in my request `------WebKitFormBoundaryQyQAQArrBFT70bfD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="technikdirekt1.png"
Content-Type: image/png` and I get HTTP 200.